# Calling a item from a queue data structure list (Python)

Tags: python, data-structures, queue

I am trying to enqueue 3 people in the list to display the results for each person with all their names at the top but was only able to achieve one result without any names:

```
Contacting the following  
Phone answered: Yes  
Booked an appointment: No  
Reshedule an appointment again.
```

I want to make the output to display the all their names and 3 outputs, one for each person from the information stored inside `'names'` , and each name to not appear twice.

I want to use a queue to prioritize them according to the list, so I'm trying to put them in order. the if and elif are conditions which will fall into either category depending on the random generator. Now, it is just that the method to include the names inside is not defined.

**Code**

```
import random

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.container = []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.size() == 0  

    def enqueue(self, item):
        self.container.append(item)

    def dequeue(self):
        self.container.pop(0)

    def size(self):
        return len(self.container)

    def peek(self) :
        return self.container[0]

names = ["Alvin", "James", "Peter"]

# Enqueuing

q = Queue()
q.enqueue(random.choice(names))

# Dequeuing and Printing
print("Contacting the following:\n" + "\n".join(q.container))  # unsure about this




for i in range(q.size()):

    answered = random.randint(0,1)
    booked = random.randint(0, 1)

    if(answered == 1 and booked == 1):
        print("Now Calling -" + (q.names)) # unsure about this
        print("Phone answered: Yes")
        print("Booked an appointment: Yes")
        print("Booking successful.")

    elif(answered==1 and booked==0):
        print("Now Calling -" + (q.names)) # unsure about this
        print("Phone answered: Yes")
        print("Booked an appointment: No")
        print("Reshedule an appointment again.")

    elif(answered == 0):
        print("Now Calling -" + (q.names)) # unsure about this
        print("Phone answered: No")
        print("Reshedule a callback.")

    q.dequeue()
```

**Example desired output:**

```
Contacting the following
Alvin
James
Peter

Now Calling - James
Phone answered: No
Reshedule a callback.
```

Comment: I was in the middle of writing an answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47736687/displaying-names-in-the-list-in-queue-data-structure#47736687) when you deleted it...

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought that I would try to figure it out myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a couple of changes to your Queue `class`. Primarily, the `.dequeue` method didn't return the item it pops, so it returns the default value of `None`.

I also changed the `.size` method to `__len__` so you can pass `Queue` instances to the built-in `len` function. And gave it an `iter` method to you can easily use it in `for` loops, or pass it to `.join`. I also changed the `.isEmpty` to `.is_empty` to conform with Python's PEP-0008 style guide.

Since you want each name to be randomly added to the queue without repetition we don't want `random.choice` here. Instead we can use`random.shuffle`; another option is to use `random.sample`, although that's more suitable when you want to make a partial selection from a list.

```
from random import seed, shuffle, randrange

# Seed the randomizer so we can reproduce results while testing
seed(9)

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.container = []

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.container)

    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self) == 0

    def enqueue(self, item):
        self.container.append(item)

    def dequeue(self):
        return self.container.pop(0)

    def peek(self) :
        return self.container[0]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.container)

names = ["Alvin", "James", "Peter"]

# Enqueuing
q = Queue()

# Make a temporary copy of the names that we can 
# shuffle without affecting the original list
temp = names.copy()
shuffle(temp)

# Put the shuffled names onto the queue
for name in temp:
    q.enqueue(name)

# Dequeuing and Printing
print("Contacting the following")
print('\n'.join(q))
#for name in q:
    #print(name)

while not q.is_empty():
    name = q.dequeue()
    print('\nNow Calling -', name)

    answered = randrange(2)
    booked = randrange(2)

    if answered:
        print("Phone answered: Yes")
        if booked:
            print("Booked an appointment: Yes")
            print("Booking successful.")
        else:
            print("Booked an appointment: No")
            print("Reshedule an appointment again.")
    else:
        print("Phone answered: No")
        print("Reshedule a callback.")
```

**output**

```
 Contacting the following
Alvin
Peter
James

Now Calling - Alvin
Phone answered: Yes
Booked an appointment: No
Reshedule an appointment again.

Now Calling - Peter
Phone answered: No
Reshedule a callback.

Now Calling - James
Phone answered: Yes
Booked an appointment: Yes
Booking successful.
```

In the above code I used

```
print('\n'.join(q))
```

to print all of the names, since you use `.join` for that purpose in your code. But I also showed the alternative way using a simple `for` loop, but I commented it out:

```
for name in q:
    print(name)
```

Comment: in the output, it shows Alvin, Peter, James instead of `names = ["Alvin", "James", "Peter"]` from the list. Is there a way that I can arrange it in order?

Comment: Also, I keep getting the same results, it seems like it shuffles itself.

Comment: @John Your code uses `random.choice`, so I thought you wanted to add the names in a random order to the queue. If you want the names to be enqueued in the original order, then just enqueue `names` and get rid of the `temp` stuff. My code use `random.shuffle` so that the random names aren't repeated. It selects the same random order on each run because we are seeding the random number with `seed(9)`. If you comment that line out then a different random order will be chose each time.

Comment: Thank you.

If I want to add a number from 1-3 in front of the name in ascending order
`for name in q:
    print(name)`

Do I use something like this
`for name in q:
    print((number += 1) + "-" + name)`

Comment: @John Python doesn't let you do assignments in expressions, so you can't do stuff like `(number += 1)`. The best way to do what you want is with the built-in `enumerate` function. Eg, `for i, name in enumerate(q, 1): print('{}-{}'.format(i, name))`